# javascript create link to directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, linux, windows

I am running a webserver on linux Centos7. It is located at local IP address 192.168.1.100.
Further, I have a Windows server running on the same network, at local IP address 192.168.1.200.

I need my users to be able to create a directory on the Windows server via the  webpages on my webserver.

However, because the webserver is linux OS, it cannot(?) create a folder directory on the windows server, despite adding ALL read/write permissions on the Windows server.

For example, on the click of a JS button on the webpage, I would want php to mkdir at 192.168.1.100/thisdirectory.

Is there a way in php to do this? Do I need to mount the windows drive on the linux server, and then use php to mkdir to the symbolic link?

I am currently using javascript & ActiveX to use the client's machine to create the windows directory - but this is not ideal.

Any thoughts on how best to do this?

Thanks,
Mat

Comment: what exactly is your question? how to make a php server accessible via lan?

Comment: how do I create a folder on the windows server using php? Note that the php is being run on a linux server

Comment: this is not possible...at least you need to have a program running on that machine where you want to create the folder...this is usually the server itself. But you cannot call a php script on machine A and create a folder on machine B without let A tell B to create the folder

Comment: can I link the drive from Windows on the linux machine, and then modify the linux machine (symbollically changing the windows directory)?

Comment: you need to have 2 servers - when your linux server is called the php script should call the windows server to create the folder

Comment: two web servers?... OK, thanks, gotcha.